# Oracle Function - Function for address indicator

Tags: database, oracle, function, plsql

I already have an existing view table which consists of 6 columns with address(2 for home address, 2 for office address and 2 for other address which came from different tables). I need to create another column(Address_indicator) in the same view table wherein it will have a value of 1 if the atleast 1 of the 6 columns have a value or 0 if none of the 6 columns have a value. To do this column im planning to create a function for this. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's very possible in general, but what is a _view table_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select your indicator value using SQL:

```
select
   case
     when address_1 is not null
     or address_2 is not null
     ...
     or address_6 is not null
     then 1
     else 0
   end address_indicator
from table
```

If the "view table" you are talking about is a "view" then you can add the case statement to the SQL of the view. No need for a function.